# SQL query to pick the next change Date from the next row based on same Brand

Tags: sql-server, lead

Requirement is to pick the next change date from the following table as

| RetailDate | Brand | IdBusinessUnit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-05 | B Series | 2 |
| 2023-02-07 | B Series | 2 |
| 2023-02-07 | Equity | 2 |
| 2023-02-15 | Equity | 2 |
| 2023-02-21 | ALL | 2 |
| 2023-03-10 | B Series | 2 |

### Need to pick the Next Change Date as new column as follows:
Desired Output

| RetailDate | Brand | NextChange | IdBusinessUnit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-05 | B Series | 2023-02-07 | 2 |
| 2023-02-07 | B Series | 2023-02-21 | 2 |
| 2023-02-07 | Equity | 2023-02-15 | 2 |
| 2023-02-15 | Equity | 2023-02-21 | 2 |
| 2023-02-21 | ALL | GETDATE() | 2 |
| 2023-03-10 | B Series | GETDATE() | 2 |

Need to traverse Row by Row to get the next Change based on Brand, if **ALL** is the Brand need to Pick the **ALL** Retaildate as NextChange as shown for B-Series (2023-02-21).

I have used the following query to get the NextChange

SELECT RetailDate
,Brand
,LEAD(RetailDate) OVER(PARTITION BY IdBusinessUnit,Brand ORDER BY RetailDate) AS NextChange
FROM  tbl_Params P (NOLOCK)
WHERE bStdActive = 1
ORDER BY RetailDate

| RetailDate | Brand | NextChange | IdBusinessUnit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-05 | B Series | 2023-02-07 | 2 |
| 2023-02-07 | B Series | 2023-03-10 | 2 |
| 2023-02-07 | Equity | 2023-02-15 | 2 |
| 2023-02-15 | Equity | NULL | 2 |
| 2023-02-21 | ALL | NULL | 2 |
| 2023-03-10 | B Series | NULL | 2 |

Please help me out, I am struggling to get the result since last 3 days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question here exactly? ["Can someone help me?" isn't an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983). What is the difficult you are having achieving your goal?

Comment: Also, do you have a *good* reason to be using `NOLOCK`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery, does the following help?

```
select *, IsNull((
    select top(1) RetailDate
    from t t2
    where t2.RetailDate > t.RetailDate
    and (t2.brand = t.brand or t2.brand = 'ALL')
    order by t2.RetailDate
), GetDate()) NextChange
from t;
```

See this [fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IthVATO0)

Answer (score 0):

This is `gaps and islands` problem, one option is to use a difference between two `row_numbers` to define Brand groups :

`MIN()` used here to return the next `Brand='ALL'`

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT RetailDate, Brand,
       MIN(case when Brand = 'ALL' then RetailDate end) over (order by RetailDate rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as next_success_time,
       LEAD(RetailDate) OVER(PARTITION BY IdBusinessUnit, Brand ORDER BY RetailDate) AS NextChange,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IdBusinessUnit ORDER BY RetailDate) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IdBusinessUnit, Brand ORDER BY RetailDate) as grp
  FROM  tbl_Params P
),
CTE2 as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by grp order by RetailDate) as rn
  from CTE
)
SELECT RetailDate, Brand, CASE WHEN next_success_time is null and NextChange is null then GetDate()
               WHEN rn = 2 THEN next_success_time
               ELSE NextChange END AS NextChange
from CTE2
ORDER BY RetailDate
```

Result :

```
RetailDate  Brand       NextChange
2023-02-05  B Series    2023-02-07 00:00:00.000
2023-02-07  B Series    2023-02-21 00:00:00.000
2023-02-07  Equity      2023-02-15 00:00:00.000
2023-02-15  Equity      2023-02-21 00:00:00.000
2023-02-21  ALL         2023-04-06 10:34:31.673
2023-03-10  B Series    2023-03-11 00:00:00.000
2023-03-11  B Series    2023-04-06 10:34:31.673
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/B1yIp9fe)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, with interleaves of brands:
https://dbfiddle.uk/Sx61yBnt

```
with data(RetailDate, Brand, IdBusinessUnit) as (
    select convert(DATETIME, '2023-02-05',102), 'B Series', 2 union all
    select convert(DATETIME,'2023-02-07',102), 'B Series', 2 union all
    select convert(DATETIME,'2023-02-07',102), 'Equity', 2 union all
    select convert(DATETIME,'2023-02-08',102), 'B Series', 2 union all
    select convert(DATETIME,'2023-02-15',102), 'Equity', 2 union all
    select convert(DATETIME,'2023-02-21',102), 'ALL', 2 union all
    select convert(DATETIME,'2023-03-10',102), 'B Series', 2 
)
select d.*,
    isnull(least(
        min (case when Brand = 'ALL' then RetailDate end) 
            over(partition by IdBusinessUnit order by RetailDate rows between 1 following and unbounded following),
        isnull(
            lead(RetailDate)  over(partition by IdBusinessUnit, brand order by retaildate),
            getdate()
        )
    ),getdate()) as nextchange
from data d
  order by RetailDate, brand
;
```